# Android Studio 3.1.1 (AVD) emulator doesn't start

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm running:

- Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit (Version 1709) (Build 16299)
- Intel i5 4690K
- 16Gb Ram
- Nvidia GeForce GTX 970
- Bios Intel virtual accellaration and HAXM (in android studio) are activated

---- As far as I can say all drivers are up to date. ---

I just ran through following steps:

- Installed - jdk-9.0.4_windows-x64_bin.exe
- Adjusted Java PATH variable in Windows and checked with "cmd --> path"
- Installed - android-studio-ide-173.4697961-windows.exe

Android Studio runs fine but whenever I try to start a virtual device i get following error messages:

See this picture for a first error message -->
[Android Studio error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UB6wC.png)

I already tried out x86_64 CPU architecture but it didn't work either.

Then I found out more error messages using emulator.exe in command prompt.
See -> [Command prompt error using emulator.exe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sW9tw.png)
Sorry for the german error message here a brief translation:

- "The procedure jump in point "_ZN10QByteArray14trimmed_helperERS_" was not found in the DLL "C:\Users...\qemu-system-x86_64.exe"

When I start the file emulator-x86.exe I receive following errormessage:
[Errormessage using emulator-x86.exe.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrklM.png)
The showed file is not the only one it claims being missed. In summary it complains about:

- libwinpthread-1.dll
- Qt5Svg.dll
- Qt5Core.dll
- Qt5Gui.dll

I can ensure you the files do exist

---

By now I found out following workaround:

- emulator.exe -avd "virtualdevicename" -force-32bit

I've got following requests:

1. I could live with the workaround. But then it would be nice having that -force-32bit parameter being set in the android studio so I'm not forced to start the virtual device via command prompt each time. How to set that up?
2. Better would be fixing the initial error. I searched for the errormessages but found nothing helpful till now.

Comment: Have you turned on Virtualization of CPU in Bios ?

Comment: As stated in the description -> Intel virtualization accelleration and HAXM are both turned on.

Comment: Right, sorry about that. Do you have problems with all emulators or just Oreo? You might try to download some other, just in case the bug is actually in their resources, and older version are "vired up" correctly. Oh, and JDK 8 as well..

Comment: In fact I tried different distributions of Android. Not just Oreo. I also already tried JDK 8. All of the changes didn't solve the issue.

I will try another emulator today and see what happens. Thanks so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the original issue hasn't been solved.
I circumvent the issue by using the "genymotion android emulator" and my android smartphone.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to actually install **the latest** version of **the Intel HAXM**:

**Windows:**

1. In your Android SDK folder, look in extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\
2. Run **intelhaxm-android.exe**

**Mac:**

1. Open the HAXM directory

> cd $ANDROID_HOME/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager

2. Run the installer:

   - Mount the HAXM *.dmg file, then run the *.mpkg contained inside it

Comment: I really appreciate the answers, but again, as stated above in the description Intel HAXM is already activated. If you're assuming a deprecated version I wanna say that the installed version is 6.2.1 which was delivered with the up-to-date Android Studio version.